# Update render in class that extends component

Tags: javascript, react-native, es6-class

How do you update the render of a react native class when it extends component?

I have tried using setState that works in the "first screen class" and in a menu/navigator class that acts as a shell of the application, but when I try to use this functions in an other class that is called from the shell I get the errormessage "Warning: getInitialState was defined on..., a plain javascript class..." and when trying to use setState or forceUpdate the message "Warning forceUpdate/setState (and so on) Can only update a mounted or mounting component.

Is there a solution to re-render by code?

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

export default class testClass extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
            super(props)
        }

    getInitialState() {
            return {
                isLoading: true,
                PackageNo: '',
                PackageNoSeq: '',
                hasError: false,
                errorMessage: '',
            };
        }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Test</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.go.bind(this)}>
          <Text>Go to Apple</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    )
  }

  go() {
    console.log("go to other");
    this.props.navigator.push({ screen: 'OtherTest' });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple highlight . React.createClass is a traditional way to declare/create a component class in React. `getInitialState` is one of `React.createClass` life cycle method and React team just released a small syntax sugar update to allow for better use with ES6 modules by `extends React.Component`, which extends the Component class instead of calling `createClass`.

The getInitialState function is deceased, and now you need to declare all state as a simple initialisation property in the constructor

```
 constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          isLoading: true,
          PackageNo: '',
          PackageNoSeq: '',
          hasError: false,
          errorMessage: ''
      }
  }
```

Comment: Ah okey, do you know how to use setState when extending? (guessing that creatClass is not needed when using extends, or is it?)

Comment: Simple, just use this.setState({obj: 'test'})

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `setState` method to rerender. Or pass props from the parent component.

```
    import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
    import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';

    export default class testClass extends Component {
      state = {
        text: 'Go to Apple'
      }

      onPress = () => {
        this.setState({text: 'Go to hell'})
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text>Test</Text>
            <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress}>
              <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </View>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: Yes that would work, but the problem is the error messages that I get that says it is a plain javascript file when using extends Component, (I have not tried onPress yet, will do it soon.

Comment: ok solved it, some kind of temporery bug in the system. Didn't change anything and it worked perfectly today.